# Links not clickable in Mozilla or Internet Explorer 11 but work in Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have a website that I am currently working on and I primarily designed it using Google Chrome.  It works as intended in Google Chrome.

My problem is this: the links at the bottom, namely Disclaimer and Privacy Info and a link to who designed it, are not click-able.  In addition, links to PDF files found on other panels do not work either.  The strangest thing is, if I have the DOM Explorer (or the Inspector) open, the links become click-able.  I have been trying to find something about this but I can't seem to find anything.  I am guessing it is something very simple that I am overlooking.  Thank you for the help in advance.

EDIT:
I think it might have something to do with this line:

```
.websiteBorder {
            z-index: -2;
            .
            .
            .
        }
```

I have attempted to recreate the problem at JSFiddle but the problem does not exist there.
Here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/willwsharp/7S8LV/1/
It looks like I cannot accurately recreate the problem so I have flagged my question for off-topic.  I would still appreciate any help if possible though, thank you.

Comment: Not relevant, but you have invalid CSS. CSS has no support for single-line comments, you need to replace "//TODO - Enforce stylistic uniformity!" with "/*TODO - Enforce stylistic uniformity!*/"

Comment: @CroaToa yes it is very bad, I knew virtually nothing when I began this site, I am sorry it is not very good.

Comment: Your question needs to contain everything required to reproduce your problem, in the question itself. Your question cannot depend on links to 3rd party sites to be meaningful and answerable, and you **definitely** cannot link to your live site as the only means of reproducing your problem. As soon as you fix your site, this question will be completely useless.

Comment: @meagar That makes sense.  I am aware of JSFiddle, but I am not sure how to reproduce my problem and site on it, I am sorry.  What should I do?

Comment: Also, I would add that you should frequently test in Firefox. Google Chrome likes to fix mistakes on rendering a webpage- giving you a false sense of security.

Comment: @Willwsharp Until you can reproduce your problem, you haven't done enough to debug the problem.  Your question *needs* to contain a minimal complete example which reproduces the problem, or it is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Blenderer Okay I will do that from now on, thank you.

Comment: @meagar Alright, should I take this question down or how should I proceed?

Comment: @Willwsharp - The best thing to do from here would be for you to create a small reproducible case, and include the code to demonstrate that case here in the question. If you can't do that, it would be best to delete the question.

Comment: Okay I will try to do that, thank you.  I will delete this question if I cannot figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `z-index: -1;` and `z-index: -2;` scattered throughout your website that is causing this. Disabling them allows you to click the anchors in both browsers, but changes the look of your site.

I suggest you rethink your approach to achieving that look.

Comment: Yes I need to re-evaluate my approach, thank you for your help.

Comment: What were you hoping to achieve with the z-index's? Maybe I can help.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, they might be a remnant of when I began this project.  If I figure out what they were used for I will get back to you, thank you.

Comment: I went back and changed the z-indexes around and it works!  I mistakenly assumed if it worked in Chrome it would work in the others.  Thank you!

Comment: Owch! Always assume the worst from other browsers :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your script to set the `#disclaimer` link falls way down in the document body.

You have a document.ready method in here, so I would move your include for not just the `transitionAndMenuScript.js` file but ALL scripts into the `<head>`.  Let them all be evaluated before the document is ready, then when the document has rendered document.ready will fire.

```
<head>
    ...
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='/google_analytics_auto.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='slideshow.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='transitionAndMenuScript.js'></script>
    ....
</head>
```

Also - I would recommend instead of `'http://code.jquery.com'` use `'//code.jquery.com'` instead.  That way it will always apply the proper URI scheme, in case you move to HTTPS for some reason.

Comment: Any luck?  Let me know if you need any more info or hit any more stumbling blocks.

Comment: Not as of yet.  I have tried to recreate the problem on JSFiddle, but the links work properly so the problem is not there.  I am currently trying to edit the question to include the link.

Comment: @Mark_S I have edited my question if you would like to take a look.